# How To Load Different CSS Style, Based On Language When Using QtranslateX

Tags: css

I want to use custom css style for every language on my site. I'm using Plugin Qtranslate-x, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of options to achieve this.

First of all, the easy way:

Qtranslate-X adds a language class to your body tag. So if you want to only have minor tweaks, you can use this in your style.css:

```
.de #page {
    background:#000;
}

.en #page {
    background:#FFF;
}
```

If you need big changes (like, you need different css-files per language), you can use the function `qtranxf_getLanguage()` in your themes enqueue_scripts action like this:

Lets say you save your styles for german language version in the file `styles-de.css` and for english language in `styles-en.css`. You now enqueue the correct style like this:

```
function mytheme_language_scripts() {
    $langcode = qtranxf_getLanguage();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'lang-style', bloginfo('stylesheet-directory').'/styles-'.$langcode.'.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_language_scripts' );
```

Happy Coding,
Kuchenundkakao